# Google OR-Tools: AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer TypeError

Tags: or-tools

In my vehicle routing problem, I am trying to minimize a cost objective function, while also adding additional variables to minimize with `routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer`.

When I do the following, however, I get a `TypeError`. What is the proper way to create an `IntVar` from two `CumulVar`s that you can then pass into `AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer`?

```py
for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    duration = time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(vehicle_id)) - time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id))
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(duration)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d27f070bd2ea> in <module>
      6 #         time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
      7     duration = time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(vehicle_id)) - time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id))
----> 8     routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(duration)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(self, var)
   3925     def AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(self, var: "IntVar") -> "void":
   3926         r""" Adds a variable to minimize in the solution finalizer. The solution finalizer is called each time a solution is found during the search and allows to instantiate secondary variables (such as dimension cumul variables)."""
-> 3927         return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(self, var)
   3928 
   3929     def AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(self, var: "IntVar") -> "void":

TypeError: in method 'RoutingModel_AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer', argument 2 of type 'operations_research::IntVar *'
```

For additional context, here is how I'm setting time windows in my code:

```py
# Create and register a time callback.
def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the travel time between two nodes."""
    ...
    return transit_time

time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

# Add time windows constraint.
routing.AddDimension(
    time_callback_index,
    10 * MIN_PER_HR * SEC_PER_MIN,  # allow waiting time
    24 * MIN_PER_HR * SEC_PER_MIN,  # maximum time per vehicle
    False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
    'Time')
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')

# Add time window constraints for each location.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
    
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    # Limit max on-duty time for each vehicle
    routing.solver().Add(
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(vehicle_id)) - time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id)) <= MAX_TIME_ON_DUTY)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use the following code instead ?

```py
routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
  time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
  time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
```

here your `duration` object is an expression...

Comment: Thanks @Mizux! Simple solution. However, this exposed a larger issue where transit time seems to not be taken into account...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63492421/google-or-tools-vrp-with-time-windows-solution-doesnt-account-for-transit-ti

Comment: I saw these rows in the tutorial example but couldn't figure out why it's needed...