# Google OR-Tools: VRP with time windows - solution doesn't account for transit time

Tags: or-tools

While trying to solve a VRP with time windows (based on the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw)), the solver does not seem to take transit time into account. Instead, it seems to assume you can jump instantaneously between nodes. Why aren't the transit and loading/unloading times in `time_dimension` being applied?

```sh
Route for vehicle 6:
 Node A: Time(36000,36000) ->
 Node B: Time(36000,36000) ->
 Node C: Time(36000,36000) ->
 Node D: Time(36000,36000) ->
 Node A: Time(36000,36000)
Cost of the route: $811.84
Timing of route: 10:0:0 - 10:0:0
Duration on-duty: 0hr, 0min, 0sec
```

I have verified that `data['time_matrix']` is not all zeros. Below is the bulk of the code for context:

```py
# Create and register a transit time callback.
def transit_time_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the travel time only between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

# Create and register a time callback.
def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the travel and dock time between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
    transit_time = transit_time_callback(from_index, to_index)
    if to_node in data['pickups']:
        dock_time = data['load_time'][to_node]
    else:
        dock_time = data['unload_time'][to_node]
    return transit_time + dock_time

time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

# Add time windows constraint.
routing.AddDimension(
    time_callback_index,
    4 * MIN_PER_HR * SEC_PER_MIN,  # allow waiting time
    24 * MIN_PER_HR * SEC_PER_MIN,  # maximum time per vehicle
    False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
    'Time')
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')

# Add time window constraints for each location.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])

# Limit max on-duty time for each vehicle
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    routing.solver().Add(
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(vehicle_id)) - time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(vehicle_id)) <= MAX_TIME_ON_DUTY)

# Minimize on-duty duration.
for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    routing.AddVariableMaximizedByFinalizer(
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
    routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
        time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))

# Set cost
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(time_callback_index)

# Solve the problem
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```

Comment: usual question: does your matrix are int ?
otherwise try to replace by this `return int(transit_time + dock_time)`

Comment: Yup, `data['time_matrix']`, `data['load_time']`, and `data['unload_time']` are all `int`. Been poking around your other responses online and noted that!

Comment: in time_callback you are using to_node but i don't see any `to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)`

Comment: did you try to add a `print(f"[{to_index},{from_index}]: {transit_time + dock_time}")` before the return of `time_callback()` ?

Comment: Adding `to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)` solved it! Thanks.